# How to automatically import contacts from Google Sheets to Elastic Email base

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to connect my Google sheets with Elastic Email base. I have a Google Form, which updates data in Google Sheets. From there I would like to send all new email addresses to my Elastic Email account, how can I achieve this?

Also another question regarding Google Sheets - with script MaillApp.SendEmail I send all form responses to my email. There is a problem, because the sender's email is my private mail, even though the form, sheet and script are on my domain's email. I can add another sender's email in the script, but then it shows both - my personal and domain's email address as senders.

Thank you very much for your help and all the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can build script that will add contact to your account with method Contact/add: http://api.elasticemail.com/public/help#Contact_Add

If you cannot build the scripts you can use integrations hub like Zapier - it should allow you to Add Contact to your Elastic Email account when certain trigger action is met (eg. new row in Google Spreadsheet).